# Emacs Tramp w/ pscp/plink on Windows

Tags: windows, emacs, tramp

I'm trying to set up emacs for editing files on my private server from our Win7 machines at school.

I have set up emacs, changed the default method in .emacs:

```
(setq tramp-default-method "pscp")
```

and downloaded pscp & plink.

The problem is, I can't edit the %path% on the local machine and I can't put pscp & plink in any location in the %path%. How do I tell Emacs where to find them?

Edit:
Turns out I can edit environment variables it just didn't show up right away and there was an unrelated problem. Editing a user environment variable of the same name as a global one seems to append the user value to the global one.

Comment: I can't even get tramp to work right over SSH *within* my Debian box...

Answer (score 2):

Emacs' `exec-path` variable would probably be helpful for this:

```
  -- User Option: exec-path
     The value of this variable is a list of directories to search for
     programs to run in subprocesses.  Each element is either the name
     of a directory (i.e., a string), or `nil', which stands for the
     default directory (which is the value of `default-directory').

     The value of `exec-path' is used by `call-process' and
     `start-process' when the PROGRAM argument is not an absolute file
     name.
```